# Showing that the series $\sum 3^{-k}{\sqrt{1-e^{-k}}}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I wish to show that the series $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1-e^{-k}}}{3^k}$ converges.

**Direct comparison test:** if $\sum b_n$ converges and $0 \le a_n \le b_n$ for all $n$ then $\sum a_n$ also converges.

Since $e^{-k} > 0$ for all $k$, we have $-e^{-k} < 0$ hence $1-e^{-k} < 1$ and thus $\sqrt{1-e^{-k}} < 1$for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Hence $ \displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{1-e^{-k}}}{3^k} \le \frac{1}{3^k}$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^k}$ converges (being a geometric series). Therefore our original series converges.

Could someone please confirm whether or not this one is correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.  Is there a particular step that you are worried about?

Comment: You should also mention something about $0\leq\sqrt{1-e^{-k}}$ if you really want it to be perfectly polished.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks. I guess it was the statement of the comparison test. On Wiki it says 'for n sufficiently large', which I guess means it doesn't has to hold for all $n$ - but if does, as in this case, all the better? Also, my inequality in the third line should be strict, but it doesn't matter I guess? Things like that.

Comment: @Clayton Thanks. I forgot about that bit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison procedure is fine. If you like to achieve extra accuracy in approximating the given series, you may notice that for any $x\in(0,1)$ we have $\sqrt{1-x}\leq 1-\frac{x}{2}$ and such inequality is pretty tight if $x$ is close to the origin. In particular
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{\sqrt{1-e^{-k}}}{3^k}=\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\sqrt{1-e^{-k}}}{3^k}\leq\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{3^k}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{(3e)^k}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2(3e-1)}\leq\frac{4}{9} $$
where the RHS is a pretty accurate approximation of the LHS.